# Evaluate $\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{2x-4}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

My question is to evaluate:

$$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{2x-4}$$

Why is the solution equal to $\frac{1}{2}\ln|x-2|$ as opposed to $\frac{1}{2}\ln|2x-4|$?

I understand that if I factor $\frac{1}{2}$ before integrating I would get the first answer, but if I don't factor before and just use $u$ substitution, why would the second answer be wrong?

Comment: Both are wrong, they both omit the $+C$. But they differ by a constant, so with $+C$ tacked on at the end, they are both (sort of) right.  Only sort of, since $\ln(|x|)+C$ is not the most general function whose derivative is $\frac{1}{x}$. But most calculus books are sloppy this way.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Which other functions have $\frac{1}{x}$ as their derivative?

Comment: Logarithmic terms from indefinite integrals are "cute" that way because for positive constants $ \ c \ $ in a term $ \ \ln | cf(x) | \ $ , we can write $ \ \ln c \ + \ \ln | f(x) | \ $ .  The numerical term $ \ \ln c \ $ can then be "absorbed" by the arbitrary constant $ \ C \ $ .

Comment: @dani_s: $f(x)=\ln(x)+47$ when $x\gt 0$, $f(x)=\ln(-x)+2014$ when $x\lt 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Similar' approach as yours bangsauce. Let $u=2x-4\;\Rightarrow\; du=2\ dx\;\Rightarrow\;du=\dfrac12\ dx$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac{dx}{2x-4}&=\frac12\int\frac{du}{u}\\
&=\frac12\ln|u|+C\\
&=\frac12\ln|2x-4|+C\quad\Rightarrow\quad\text{your solution}\\
&=\frac12\ln2|x-2|+C\\
&=\frac12\ln|x-2|+\frac12\ln 2+C\quad\Rightarrow\quad\ln ab=\ln a +\ln b\\
&=\frac12\ln|x-2|+K\quad\Rightarrow\quad\text{where }K=\frac12\ln 2+C\text{ , yield another solution}.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\ln|2x-4|=\ln(2|x-2|)=\ln 2+\ln|x-2|$$

i.e., $$\frac12\ln|2x-4|-\ln|x-2|=\ln2 $$ which is a constant

So, $$\frac{d\left(\frac12\ln|2x-4|\right)}{dx}=\frac{d\left(\frac12\ln|x-2\right)}{dx}$$

---

Alternatively,
 $$\frac12\ln|2x-4|+k=\frac12\left(\ln 2+\ln|x-2|\right)=k'+\frac12\ln|x-2|$$ where $$k'=k+\frac12\ln2$$